# After Data Migration Product Listing Not Showing

Tags: magento2.2, data-migration-tool

**I've migrated(using Magento tool) from M1.8.1.0 To M2.2.4, Migration has done but product listing not showing on M2 site while products have assigned to all categories successfully after migration.**

When I update a product without any modification from the admin then it shows on the product listing page corresponding to the assigned category.

It means that I've to update products to show in their categories.

Is this migration bug? how can I resolve this issue easily?

Thanks!!!

Comment: tried reindexing and cleared cache?

Comment: @Kalyan, Yup! I already tried & it's works.

Comment: run below command php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have tired reindexing but still my issue persists.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have tired reindexing but still my issue persists.

Comment: @wakarAhamad Logi to admin end and check whether the product main website checked and saved properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

First I did a reindex:

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And then I enabled the setting `Display Out of Stock Products` in `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=> Give permissions to pub/media folder chmod -R 777 pub/media
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the Elasticsearch service start or not,